# FileNotFoundException when I tried to run an Excel AddIn

Tags: c#, excel, excel-addins

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;

namespace ExcelAddIn1
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private UserControl1 userControl;
        private Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane myCustomTaskPane;

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            userControl = new UserControl1();
            //myCustomTaskPane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(myAddIn, "My Task Pane");
            myCustomTaskPane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(userControl, "Enter Text");
            myCustomTaskPane.Visible = true; 
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

I created a Excel AddIn that uses a User Control with 2 buttons to add text and add Image in to the Excel sheet. I have compiled the code without errors but while running it is throwing the following exception

> Cannot find the file specified ( Exception from HRESULT:0x80070002)